# How to have a user input to Math.js

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to be able to convert a user given amount to another quantity on a website using `Math.js` and an input box but whatever I try will not be able to get the users input from the input box labeled "convert" and change it. How could I achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/zFuNs/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Convert</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/josdejong/mathjs/master/dist/math.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="convert"></input>
        <script>
            function print(value) {
                document.write(math.format(value) + '<br>');
            }

            print(math.eval('"TEXT IN CONVERT BOX HERE" inch in cm'));
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try learning some basic JS, and some library like jQuery.

> jQuery is a lightweight, "write less, do more", JavaScript library.
>
> The purpose of jQuery is to make it much easier to use JavaScript on
>   your website.
>
> jQuery takes a lot of common tasks that require many lines of
>   JavaScript code to accomplish, and wraps them into methods that you
>   can call with a single line of code.
>
> jQuery also simplifies a lot of the complicated things from
>   JavaScript, like AJAX calls and DOM manipulation.

here is a working example of your question http://jsfiddle.net/zFuNs/3/

```
$('#convert').click(function () {
    var cm = math.eval( $('#inch').val() + ' inch in cm' );
    $('#cms').text(cm);
});
```